# Insert data from linked server to another server in SQL without using openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, exec, linked-server, openquery

I am trying to query data from a table in a linked server and insert it into a table in another server. I know this may easily be done using openquery(), however, I am not able to use that function here as my query is *longer than the 800 character limit*. So after some research I saw that I must use EXEC instead. I am still receiving errors. I know Oracle is a component as well and perhaps that is why the [server].[db].[schema].[table] syntax does not work.

I have never worked with linked servers before and I am fairly new to sql anyway so maybe there is something obvious I am missing although I have been researching this for quite some time now. Any tips or suggestions for an alternative method is much appreciated !

A shell of my code is below.

```
    Declare @sql varchar(max) = 
'
SELECT * INTO [server_name].[DB_name].[schema_name].[table]
FROM
(
select ….
from 
) x'

EXEC (@sql) AT [Linked_Server_Name]
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Why are you using dynamic sql? Are the Linked Servers setup correctly?

Comment: @SS_DBA To my knowledge the servers are set up correctly. I have been able to query them fine. The error I am getting is ORA-00936: missing expression which appears you get for a number of reason…..I am using dynamic sql because that is the best solution I found to deal with openquery's character limit. Would you suggest a different method?

Comment: Ok. So there's a piece of missing information. Oracle server. Is this the source or destination? Why not use SSIS for this?

Comment: @SS_DBA The linked server is the source and my sql database is the destination. If I were to use SSIS what would be the source object in the data flow to connect to my linked server in sql? I am not using SSIS at the moment as I am not sure if I will have privileges to install visual studio on my remote desktop

Comment: In SSIS, you would create in the Connection manager, a Source object that pointed to the Oracle server. Execute the query on that source, the direct the output to the SQL Server Destination object.